# How to improve email verification

Tags: user-interface, captcha, spam, user-registration

I have a question about email verification and user registration. The other day I created accounts for both [Twitter](http://twitter.com) and [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) and I realized in either of them I was asked to fill a CAPTCHA. And even before validating my email account I could already use my account and add friends and all that. Supposedly I had limited options, but didn't even realized it.

My question is, as I'm building a website with user registration myself and I'm planning on use this method, how to deal with spam, "junk accounts" and people that don't validate their email accounts?

And more realistically, I was thinking either asking for a CAPTCHA and an email (and let users verify their accounts later on) or asking for an email and waiting for it to be verified (with a link or a temporal password) right away. In this case, which is the best option?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's debate question which is good or bad.
I personally feel Use email verification by sending link on email account and verify that link on click. This will let you trusted user.

By the way [captcha](http://www.thegeminigeek.com/what-is-captcha/) isn't bad. It will prevent automated account creation strongly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man... Yes I guess captcha + email verification is the most secure option. But would you recommend asking the user to verify his/her email account immediatly? or let him/her navigate and do stuff without being verified?

Comment: It's upto your site need of security by `email verification`. It would be more secure if you use captcha + email verification. You can `navigate user without being verified tell him verify account by email verification within 1 week. Otherwise your account will be deleted.`